# $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} f'(x)}$ imples $f$ differentiable at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Suppose the function $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-1, 1)$ and $f'$ exists on $(-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$. Moreover, $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} f'(x)}$.

Prove (or disprove) that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

It seems to me that the right derivative at $0$ exists, but there is no evidence that the left derivative of $f$ at $0$ exists! However, I failed to find a counterexample. If the claim is wrong, can we use some stronger continuity condition of $f$ to make it differentiable at $0$?

Comment: What makes you think the right derivative exists but not the left derivative? That property should be symmetric.

Comment: Use definition of derivative and de l'Hopital's Theorem.

Comment: Doesn't $f(-x)$ satisfy the same hypothesis? Doesn't the right derivative of $f(-x)$ give the left derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: @spinosarus123 Thanks for the comments! I though we have no information of the left derivative at $0$, because we only have for right derivative $\lim_{x\to 0+} f'=\lim_{x\to 0-} f'$

Comment: @dfnu Ok Let me try a proof

Comment: try using lagrange theorem and haine defenition of a limit

Answer (score 2):

$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$

Use le Hopital's rule:

$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-0}{1}$.

Suppose $\lim_{x\to0+} f'=\lim_{x\to 0-}f'=C$

Then $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-0}{1}=C$ for both left and right derivatives?

Comment: You prove that $f'(0)$ exists by assuming $f'(0)$ exists.

Comment: That's correct if the two limits are finite. I don't understand from your hypothesis if you must also consider the case in which the two limits are equal but e.g. $+\infty$.

Comment: The statement in the first line of your answer is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Using the mean value theorem we get

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(y)$$ where $0<y<x$. Taking limits gives us $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x).$$ By a similar argument we get $$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x).$$ Because the positive and negative limit are both equal the limit exists and
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x).$$